# Check condition for a zip file in UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, zip, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

This is my code for calling UIDocumentPickerViewController to choose the files for my firmware update which have to be `.zip` only. When I press on "Select" button, the Document Picker View shows up:

```
@IBAction func selectButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
   if sender.title(for: .normal) == "Select"{
      if let controller = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.currentViewController {
         let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeArchive)], in: .open )
         importMenu.delegate = self
         importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
         controller.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
    } else {
       changeDFUItemsDesign(isFileURLNil: true)
  }
}
```

Right now it's possible to open the files in `.docx` format, but I need to only let the user pick one format - a zip file.

I cannot present what I have done so far because I am not able to find a solution. Is there a way to make a check for a zip file or just forbid selecting other formats? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view's extension I use the `UIDocumentPickerDelegate` and in the function I check if my file's last component is zip:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
   if let fileURL = urls.first, fileURL.pathExtension == "zip" {
      self._fileURL = fileURL
      self.fileNameLabel.text = _fileURL?.lastPathComponent
    } else {
      _fileURL = nil
      fileNameLabel.text = "Select file"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Intialize the DocumentPicker with the list of supported types.

```
    let zip = ["com.pkware.zip-archive"]
    let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: zip, in: .import)
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)'s a list of supported UTIs

Comment: hi and thank you for the answer. Basically, this is the same as what I am using, you just make initialize the type separately: ```let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeArchive)], in: .open )``` The problem is that ```.docx``` is considered to be an archive as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40037942/11219710 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML