# How to use XDocument to replace some nodes in a docx file but then resave to a stream which is uploaded to MS Graph

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I am struggling to work with XDocument to parse some data and change some values for docx file. I am able to download the file, I am able to parse the file, then I can replace those nodes in question but then when it comes to saving the file it always corrupts it. When I compare docText in the code below to the parsed values if I did .ToString() and compare what parse does, it adds some additional tags (xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main") which i am wondering if parse cannot be reused to go backwards back to the docx file. My code is as follows:

```
using (var memoryStream = await oneDrive.DriveItemDownloadAsync(SharedDriveID, filePathSourceMemo, "path"))
{
    var DraftDocumentMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
    {
        docText = null;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        try
        {

            var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(docText);

            xDoc.Save(DraftDocumentMemoryStream);
            DraftDocumentMemoryStream.Position = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

        var UploadResponse = await oneDrive.UploadFileStreamAsync(SharedDriveID, DraftDocumentMemoryStream, filePathDestinationMemo, "replace");
}
```

I know my download and upload functions for MS Graph API work as I have saved streams from WordProcessingDocument directly and it always is good. Its this xml parser that seems to break things when i got to save as a stream. I also am not able to reopen those xdocument streams in WordProcessingDocument because it will then say file is corrupt.

Comment: What is `ms`?  In your code you do `xDoc.Save(ms); ms.Position = 0;` but `ms` is never declared.  Only `DraftDocumentMemoryStream` is declared -- but is never actually filled with anything.

Comment: My apologies I changed ms to DraftDocumentMemoryStream to be more descriptive for stackoverflow but missed that spot. It should be changed in the code above now.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are actually trying to accomplish with your code.  Might you please [edit] your question to explain what changes you are making in the docx file at a user-visible level? A [mcve] including initial text we could paste into a docx of our own for testing would be ideal.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay so I have removed excess code of any manipulation to the docx file since its irrelevant to the issue unfortunately. I download the docx file. I parse it. Then I want to save this parsed xml data structure back to a stream which is uploaded to ms graph api. I just tested this dumbbed down version and still the file is corrupted even if I do not manipulate the docx at all. I believe I am using xDoc.Save() incorrectly or thinking that it can be reused as a docx memorystream.

Comment: Are you using [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK)? What are you attempting to do with _XDocument_? Is this _ChatGPT_ generated code? Please refer to the [DocumentFormat.OpenXml documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.8.1).

Comment: A docx file is not an XML file.  It is a **zip archive** containing multiple XML files (and possibly other file types such as images.)  See [What is the structure of a .docx and .doc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40037905).  So if you extract a single XML file from the archive and try to replace the archive itself with the XML component, of course the result will be corrupt.

Comment: Yea I think i may be overworked or just dumb. My solution to this problem was to actually just do docx.ToString() and wriet that with the streamwriter to the wordDoc object. Worked like a charm but I am not sure why it took me so long to realize that is the best method!

Comment: @user246821 I did not know you could generate code from ChatGPT. Have you used it for coding?

Comment: _I did not know you could generate code from ChatGPT_:  Doubtful. _Have you used it for coding?_: No, but it seems that you may have - unsuccessfully though.